# Can I break out of a python generator?

Tags: python

Consider the following string

```
long_string = '#' * 4 + 'a' * 10 + '#' * 4

print(long_string)

####aaaaaaaaaa####
```

I want to cycle through and get only the first several characters until the character is **Not** a `'#'`

I can iterate through and get at just the `'#'`

```
''.join(x for x in long_string if x.startswith('#'))

'########'
```

This is too many.

I want to do something like this

```
def gen_break(long_string, mychar):
    i = iter(long_string)
    s = next(i)
    while s == mychar:
        yield s
        s = next(i)

''.join(gen_break(long_string, '#'))

'####'
```

This stopped iterating when it encountered a condition for which to break.  Is there a way to do this more elegantly within the `(this for this in that)` syntax?

---

**NOTE:**
This was a contrived example in order to highlight the question I am asking.  I'm not looking for a way to parse this example string.  I'm looking for a way to break out of iteration in an elegant way, preferably using comprehension syntax.

Comment: You can't `break` in a genexp. You can use `itertools.takewhile`, though.

Comment: [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) does exactly this

Comment: Could you deliberately set up your situation/generator so that it causes an error precisely at the point you want to break out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [**`itertools.takewhile`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) function:

```
from itertools import takewhile

''.join(takewhile(lambda x:x == '#','#### foo bar ### qux'))
```

this then generates:

```
>>> ''.join(takewhile(lambda x:x == '#','#### foo bar ### qux'))
'####'
```

So as long as the predicate (the first argument) of `takewhile` is satisfied, it iterates through the iterable (the second argument). From the moment the predicate is not satisfied, `takewhile` will stop. It will not exhaust the remaining(s) of the iterable/iterator.

As far as I know you can not do this with list comprehension/generator/... syntax.